# How to get  Type value from assembly

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I have the lines of code shown below

Can anybody provide me the code which will create `type` value as shown below

The exception I get is: `" ex = {"Could not load file or assembly , Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutr..."`

Comment: What error do you get with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

If you do have the file: _UNIX_Linux_TesterTEST-MACHINE.dll, then you should look for the libraries that this one depends on.  One way to find out which they are is to run Fuslogw.exe(the Assembly Binding Log Viewer).

/Tibi

Comment: i dont have any libraries like that these all are specially created for  this situation

Comment: What is the type of xmlSerializableType?

Comment: it is type of XmlSerializableType wich is a class    [Serializable]
   public class XmlSerializableType : XmlBaseClass
   {